# Have I chosen the right model for the analysis?

Tags: r, biostatistics, genetics

1. **What kind of data I have?** I have *.csv file with the following structure:

   ```
   str (SNPs)
   'data.frame':   2240 obs. of  16 variables:
    $ group     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    $ sample    : Factor w/ 2234 levels "1000","1003",..: 1109 2064 107 306...
    $ lost      : Factor w/ 6 levels ">6","2","3",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ ACE       : Factor w/ 3 levels "D/D","I/D",..: 1 2 2 3 4 4 3 1 2 2 ...
    $ eNOS.ab   : Factor w/ 3 levels "a/a","a/b",..: 1 4 4 3 4 4 3 1 3 4 ...
    $ eNOS.GT   : Factor w/ 3 levels "G/G","G/T",..: 1 3 2 3 2 2 4 1 2 2 ...
    $ PAI       : Factor w/ 3 levels "4g/4g","4g/5g",..: 3 2 3 2 2 4 2 3 ...
    $ FI        : Factor w/ 3 levels "Ala/Ala","Thr/Ala",..: 1 4 4 4 4 3 ...
    $ FV        : Factor w/ 2 levels "G/A","G/G": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
    $ FXIII     : Factor w/ 3 levels "Leu/Leu","Val/Leu",..: 1 4 3 3 4 4 4 ...
    $ FII       : Factor w/ 2 levels "G/A","G/G": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
    $ Vegf      : Factor w/ 3 levels "C/C","G/C",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ HIF       : Factor w/ 3 levels "C/C","C/T",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
    $ MTHFR.677 : Factor w/ 3 levels "C/C","C/T",..: 2 2 2 3 1 3 1 2 3 2 ...
    $ MTHFR.1298: Factor w/ 3 levels "A/A","A/C",..: 4 3 2 2 1 3 1 3 2 3 ...
    $ MTR       : Factor w/ 3 levels "A/A","A/G",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
   ```

   - "group": 0 - pacients (cases), 1 - control group;
   - "samples" and "lost" - they are not important now;
   - other columns contains results of genotyping. Name of this columns - it is name of analized polimorphizm.

   I have a small fake dataset here: [my_data5.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7WmigXfo613ejhlZVBmcEQybGM/view?usp=sharing). Below, I use it to show all examples.
2. **What I want to do?** I want to make haplotype analysis, using library(SNPassoc). I also have some [documentation](http://www.creal.cat/media/upload/arxius/jr/SNPassoc.pdf). I want to analize all posible combinations of all genotypes comparing with control group, using my data. The result is looks like this (analize combinations of ACE and Vegf genotypes, comparing with control group):

   ```
        freq   or   95%   C.I.   P-val 
   IG 0.3868   1.00 Reference haplotype 
   DC 0.1382   1.63 (   0.71 -   3.75 )  0.2481 
   DG 0.3287   0.69 (   0.31 -   1.54 )  0.3661 
   IC 0.1462   1.68 (   0.64 -   4.38 )  0.2889
   ```

   - First line - "IG". "I" - it is allele of the ACE polimorphism; "G" - it is allele of the Vegf polimorphism;
   - Second line - "DC". "D" - it is allele of the ACE polimorphism; "C" - it is allele of the Vegf polimorphism;
   - and etc.
3. **How I do this?** My code you can find below (I use fictional dataset, which share above):

   ```
   library(SNPassoc) #library(SNPassoc) use some functions from library(haplo.stats)

   # load my data
   SNPs <- read.csv2("my_data5.csv")
   # preparing data
   datSNP <- setupSNP(SNPs, 2:4, sep="/")
   # this polimorphisms (SNPs) will by analized. The order of the SNPs is important!
   a <- c("ACE", "Vegf")
   # prepare a model matrix with these genotypes
   tag.SNPs <- as.vector(a)
   geno <- make.geno(datSNP,tag.SNPs)

   # my question is here. Start analize. 
   # I use bimomial test, because it's case-control study.
   mod <- haplo.glm(group~geno, data=SNPs, family=binomial, haplo.freq.min=0.05)

   #show result in console
   intervals(mod)
   ```
4. **So, what do I not understand?** I want compare combinations of genotypes in cases and control groups (case-control; column "group" in my *.csv data; 0-case, 1-control). But is it right to use "**group~geno**"? Is it the correct model? Does it really compare cases and controls?